# How do you turn column names into row values for a timeseries data.frame in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I have time series data that looks like the following:
[Image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI3lp.png)

Here is an example of the format it is currently in but with easier numbers:

```
Datetime             co2_50cm     co2_15cm    co2_5cm   co2_0cm
2011-08-19 18:00:00  10           20          30        40
2011-08-19 19:00:00  1            2           3         4
```

I am attempting to get the depth of each measurement in cm as a separate column that repeats for each datetime value.

The format I am looking for is as follows:

```
Datetime             depth co2
2011-08-19 18:00:00  0     40 
2011-08-19 18:00:00  5     30 
2011-08-19 18:00:00  15    20
2011-08-19 18:00:00  50    10
2011-08-19 19:00:00  0     4 
2011-08-19 19:00:00  5     3 
2011-08-19 19:00:00  15    2
2011-08-19 19:00:00  50    1
```

What I am really struggling with is how to do this while maintaining the correct Datetime values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. This converts your data to long format and then changes the character strings with your depth to integers.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Datetime, names_to = "depth", values_to = "co2") %>% 
  mutate(depth = gsub("co2_", "", depth), 
         depth = as.integer(gsub("cm", "", depth))) %>% 
  arrange(Datetime, depth)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Datetime            depth   co2
  <chr>               <int> <int>
1 2011-08-19 18:00:00     0    40
2 2011-08-19 18:00:00     5    30
3 2011-08-19 18:00:00    15    20
4 2011-08-19 18:00:00    50    10
5 2011-08-19 19:00:00     0     4
6 2011-08-19 19:00:00     5     3
7 2011-08-19 19:00:00    15     2
8 2011-08-19 19:00:00    50     1
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = F, text = 
"Datetime|co2_50cm|co2_15cm|co2_5cm|co2_0cm
2011-08-19 18:00:00|10|20|30|40
2011-08-19 19:00:00|1|2|3|4")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = c("Datetime"), names_to = 'co2')[,
       depth :=  sub(".*_(\\d+).*", "\\1", variable)][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pivot_longer` you can use `names_pattern` argument to get the data in separate columns.

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, 
                    cols = -Datetime, 
                    names_pattern = '(co2)_(\\d+)cm', 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'depth'))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  Datetime            depth   co2
#  <dttm>              <chr> <int>
#1 2011-08-19 18:00:00 50       10
#2 2011-08-19 18:00:00 15       20
#3 2011-08-19 18:00:00 5        30
#4 2011-08-19 18:00:00 0        40
#5 2011-08-19 19:00:00 50        1
#6 2011-08-19 19:00:00 15        2
#7 2011-08-19 19:00:00 5         3
#8 2011-08-19 19:00:00 0         4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Datetime = structure(c(1313776800, 1313780400), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), co2_50cm = c(10L, 1L), 
co2_15cm = c(20L, 2L), co2_5cm = c(30L, 3L), co2_0cm = c(40L, 4L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```